# Does anyone have the criss cross algorithm programming code to solve linear programming problems?

Tags: linear-programming, python, algorithms, simplex, matlab

I have a project that requires programming code for the simplex algorithm and criss-cross algorithm. The purpose of this project is to compare the two methods. I've tried to find it, but the programming code for the criss-cross algorithm is very difficult to find. Maybe someone can help me find the source or someone already has it. Or if you have another source that has it, please simply drop the link below. I'll use the programming code to solve linear programming problems. Any program doesn't matter as long as it can solve the problem of the linear program. Thank you very much.

For those who don't know about the Criss Cross algorithm I'm referring to, you can visit this link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Criss-cross_algorithm

Comment: How does criss cross compare to dual simplex fir MILP nodes?

Comment: Is the criss cross algorithm the best kept secret in O.R., or is it secret for a reason (i.e, has no merit vs. (dual) simplex or IPM)?

Comment: a comparision paper: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1111/1475-3995.00392?casa_token=g-cX-s_vrSQAAAAA:DO1I6jV7jgnbfMOZ6ngLpxMTEmCZL1-N8XU9mTXx-_7CqYkczKlwD4OoJEhRgnW-ZJjuoyT9dbM3aBw

Comment: @user3680510 Do you have, or is there, a free synopsis of the results of the paper you linked? Thanks.

Comment: @user3680510 thank you so much for the reference paper, and it is very helpful